# including header causes parse issues

Tags: c++, boost, cocos2d-x, objective-c++

I wrote an Objective-C Wrapper for C++, so in the main file, I just have to use C++ Code. In a test project it works perfectly finde so I wanted to implement in a fairly big game. The problem is, after I only use

```
#include "ViewWrapper.hpp"
```

in my base node class (`CCNode.h` from Cocos2d-x) I get a lot of Parse, Semantic and Leixcal or Prepocessor Issues in another file (`named_params.hpp` from "Boost") without really using it, only writing the include. If I delete it, everything works fine. Does anyone know what the cause of this can be?

(In my test-project, I included it in `CCNode` too, there was no problem.)

Edit: Code of `ViewWrapper.hpp`:

```
#ifndef __Cocos__ViewWrapper__
#define __Cocos__ViewWrapper__

#include <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>
#include <CoreGraphics/CGColor.h>

class ViewWrapper
{
public:
    const char* accessibilityLabel();
    void setAccessibilityLabel(const char* accessibilityLabel);

    CGRect accessibilityFrame();
    void setAccessibilityFrame(CGRect accessibilityFrame);

    CGRect frame();
    void setFrame(CGRect frame);

    CGColorRef backgroundColor();
    void setBackgroundColor(CGFloat r, CGFloat g, CGFloat b, CGFloat a);

    ViewWrapper (CGRect frame);
    ViewWrapper (void);
    ~ViewWrapper (void);
private:
    struct Impl;
    Impl* impl;
};
#endif /* defined(__Cocos__ViewWrapper__) */
```

Hope that helps.

The error is in `struct nil {...}`. Maybe it has some problems with nil because Objective-C uses nil and my Wrapper wrapps Objective-C code? But my header is a `.hpp` file...

ANSWER (can't answer correctly because it's on hold):
I removed the two includes

```
#include <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>
#include <CoreGraphics/CGColor.h>
```

and used cocos header like `CCGeometry.h` and `ccTypes.h` so the header has NO objective-C code and the compiler doesn't get confused with the boost version of nil.

Comment: Then you have some error in your header file. Are you missing a preprocessor `#endif`? Missing semicolons? Missing or extra braces (`{` or `}`)?

Comment: Without more details is difficult to say... check for preprocessor macros redefining stuff, check for unclosed #endif, unclosed }, check for using namespaces in the headers.

Comment: There must be some error in the header file itself.. look for some silly mistakes...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I copy pasted the header file from my test project, and there it works just fine. But I still looked for some errors and can't find any. Can the problem still lie in the header? And I didn't change the `named_params.hpp`. There is says for example "Delcaration of anonymous struct must be a definition. But there can't be a problem in this file, I didn't touch it and it would crash even if I don't include the header file.

Comment: Without either the code or the errors (and preferably would be to see both), there is nothing we can to.

Comment: I wanted to post an image of the errors, but I need a reputation of 10 to upload images.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on a missing `;` after a class, enum, enum class or struct declaration:

```
struct AprilFool
{

}

// IMPAHTANT:
;
// END IMPAHTANT
```

Comment: Strong possibility...

Comment: This is a very common error, also visual studio just goes crazy with the errors.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in my code it's not that. I copy pasted my functional `ViewWrapper.hpp`.

Answer (score 0):

What file extension does the file have that this is included from? The one all the errors are shown from?

As far as compilers are concerned, headers do not exist. They compile only source files. Any headers that are compiled are effectively "copied into the source file", right in the spot where the include statement would be.

So if you include this file from a .m file, it gets compiled as .m (Objective-C). No matter that the header has the suffix ".hpp". (If you want to know more about this, look up "compilation units" in a good book on C, or listen to NSBrief episode 113, where I was asked to explain all things Objective-C++: http://nsbrief.com/113-uli-kusterer/).

It'd also help to know what includes you have. Is the include of this header the first? Last? Is the one giving the errors the next include right after it? Is there any code in the file that includes this? If you make it the last include, does it work, or does it just error on the next line after the includes? Errors made at the end of one header can, after all "spill over" into the next line, be that one copy-pasted by an include statement or in the same header.

Comment: My `ViewWrapper.hpp` is included in `CCNode.h` which is included in `CCNode.cpp` and it's the last include. So it is right after all the standard includes from `CCNode.h`.
Like I said, the wrappers work just fine in my test project, where the same file is included in the same header. `ViewWrapper.hpp` is also included in `ViewWrapper.mm` if you want to know.

Comment: Well, that *should* work the way you describe it, so you've probably left something out, or re-typed the code and implicitly fixed the issue by accident. Do the errors come from the .cpp file? Or from the .mm file? Or do you get them for both? What exact errors are you getting?